# Why does Finder append `.app` to a file with `.service`

Tags: macos, finder, file-extensions

If have a file called `gunicorn.service` (a file for `Linux`) on my Mac. However, Finder shows `gunicorn.service.app` as filename with a weird "forbidden app" icon. When checking info (cmd+I) with name and extension, it says the name without the `.app` extension.

Finder's advanced setting "Show all filename extensions" doesn't change this behaviour.

Why is that? And can it be disabled?